# android - Как сделать индикатор вкладки без самих вкладок?

Tags: android

Я не хочу использовать `Tab` и поэтому заменил вкладки на `ViewFlipper`. Навигация происходит по кнопкам, выставленным горизонтально в ряд. Мне нужен индикатор в виде полоски под кнопкой, которая будет перемещаться под нажатую кнопку. Как такое реализовать?  Создать эту `View` в разметке и программно ее перемещать? Или есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewFlipper хорош для слайд навигации(читай показывать слайды, плюс анимация), а если вам нужно показывать и управлять вкладками, то лучше использовать ViewPager, как более достойный вариант управления табами. Кастомизации viewPager целая куча, для начала посмотрите отдельный проект на [гитхабе](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip). Если же вы не хотите использовать нативный механизм управления табами, тогда кастомизируйте кнопку - создайте слой(чуть побольше кнопки layout_margin:bottom = 3dp), на который вы наложите кнопку и при нажатии на эту кнопку меняйте ему бакграунд. как-то так

Comment: Да ну это все. ViewFlipper. Не хочу еще и над интерфейсом плясать.